# Eigenvalues of differentiable paths

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Define $W$ a vector spaces. Let $\alpha(t):W\to W$ be a differentiable linear mapping. Furthermore, let $\lambda_1 (t), \lambda_2 (t), \cdots$ denote the eigenvalues of $\alpha(t)$.

Intuitively, I am guessing $\lambda'_1 (t), \lambda'_2 (t), \cdots$ will be the eigenvalues of $\alpha'(t)$. If this statement is true, could you give me a hint on how to prove it? If it is not true, please point it out.

Comment: Eigenvalues of a linear map $T\colon V\to W$ don't make sense. You need $V=W$. Even Isomorphic is not good enough. But the question doesn't make sense even if $\alpha(t)\colon W\to W$. You need to say that each $\alpha(t)$ is a linear mapping.

Comment: Your guess is correct only when the eigenvectors of $\alpha(t)$ are constant. The general case is quite subtle - see e.g. Kato's book *A Short Introduction to Perturbation Theory for Linear Operators*. If you're just looking for a formula then you can find a lot by searching the web for something like *derivative of eigenvalues*.